# Zustand perform action on a store created with init props

Tags: reactjs, zustand

Following the [Zustand docs here](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/initialize-state-with-props#store-creator-with-createstore), I have created a Zustand store with initial props.

```
export const useNameStore = (initProps?: Partial<NameStoreProps>) =>
  create<NameStore>()(
    subscribeWithSelector((set) => ({
      ...defaultProps,
      ...initProps,
      updateName: (name) => set(() => ({ name })),
    })),
  );
```

Inside another component I utilize the store in this way

```
 const [name, updateName] = useNameStore({ name: "init" })((state) => [
    state.name,
    state.updateName,
  ]);
```

The issue is when I call the `updateName` action, it does not updates the name with the new value.

I tried removing the initProps logic from the store and everything works fine.

```
export const useNameStore =
  create<NameStore>()(
    subscribeWithSelector((set) => ({
      ...defaultProps,
      ...initProps,
      updateName: (name) => set(() => ({ name })),
    })),
  );
```

The [complete link to the First issue sandbox is here.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-zustand-init-d7c42y?file=%2Fsrc%2FNameStore.ts%3A18%2C1-25%2C5)

Comment: Is it so I need to create some wrapper around the useNameStore in order to use the action?